# Invalid syntax not being displayed on Python Idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

whenever i run this code it comes up with invalid syntax but i dont know which parts wrong (idle isnt showing the error). If you could help it'd be aprecciated

```
go = True
def loop():

    response1 = input ("Enter number: ")   
    print ("Thank you for " + response1)
    number1 = int(response1)
    response2 = input ("Enter second number: ")
    print ("Thank you for " + response2)
    number2 = int(response2)
    if int(number1) == int(number2):
        print (str(number1) + " is equal to " + str(number2))
        elif int(number1) != int(number2):
            print (str(number1) + " is not equal to " + str(number2))

while go:
    loop()
```

Comment: on which line do you get the `SyntaxError`?

Comment: it doesnt show which line and i cant find the error myself. not sure why

Comment: So who is showing the error?

Comment: Your `elif` should have the same indent as your `if` -- also, you don't need to recheck the condition. It should just be `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your indentation for `elif`:

```
if int(number1) == int(number2):
    print (str(number1) + " is equal to " + str(number2))
elif int(number1) != int(number2):
    print (str(number1) + " is not equal to " + str(number2))
```

Answer (score 2):

elif indention is not correct. See below

```
go = True
def loop():

    response1 = input ("Enter number: ")   
    print ("Thank you for " + response1)
    number1 = int(response1)
    response2 = input ("Enter second number: ")
    print ("Thank you for " + response2)
    number2 = int(response2)
    if int(number1) == int(number2):
        print (str(number1) + " is equal to " + str(number2))
    elif int(number1) != int(number2):
        print (str(number1) + " is not equal to " + str(number2))

while go:
    loop()
```